# Is it possible to change a hyperlink based on where it's not linked to?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, you know how in css this `[href*='www.example.com']` will grab every link that goes to `www.example.com`? Is it possible to do the opposite? In other words, grab every link that doesn't point to `www.example.com`.

If this isn't possible with css, would it be possible to do with jquery?

Comment: have you tried the :not() selector? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `$("[href!='www.example.com']")`.